# How to use enum within HTML?

Tags: javascript, angular

When I reference to an enum value I am getting below error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Text' of undefined
```

Is there any way to use this enum within html part of component?

My Enum;

```
 export enum InputType {
    Text = "text",
    Number = "number",
    Color = "color"
}
```

My component;

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  inputType : InputType;

}
```

html part;

```
<app-input [inputType]="inputType.Text"></app-input>
```

Comment: You need to assign the inputType -> `inputType = InputType;`. Otherwise, `inputType` is declared as type "InputType" but is **never assigned**, hence it will be **undefined** at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  inputType : InputType;

}
```

to:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  inputType = InputType;

}
```

Otherwise, inputType will be treated by typescript as an `InputType`, but will never be **assigned**, hence it will be `undefined` at runtime (and angular will throw the exception as stated above, since it's trying to access a property of an undefined component property).